# JPA Read but not write/update an attribute

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a JPA Entity that has an attribute declared in the following way

```
 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserBare user;
```

(UserBare is a dummy entity I've created which is a dumbed down version of a User obj as I needed some date, not all of User obj be made available to this entity. Is there a better way to approach this?

This is a convenience attr that I use just make the userBare object available to this entity when reading this entity. But when I actually write this entity, it seems to create new entries of 'user' in the database (instead of updating). I already have insertable=false,updatable=false but it still writes to the database. I tried removing the CascadeType declaration but that is throwing an error.

Here is the database snapshot after the unwanted rows are added (last 3). Also I've noticed that deleting the original entity did not delete these three unwanted rows. So I guess JPA is storing them but the references are intact to the original entity.

[image]

Comment: Just curious - what happens if your UserBare is just an interface, and your 'heavy' user is implementing that?

Answer (score 1):

My souspicioun would be that "OneToOne" means "OneToOne" excluding the possibility of "OneToZero" if you don't set Optional to true like this:

```
@OneToOne(optional=true)
```

But just a guess.. I'm not sure